# Lenovo USB 3 to Ethernet adaptor not working on Nexus Player

Tags: networking, usb-drivers, usb-on-the-go, android-tv

I have a Nexus 5, a Nexus Player, a USB OTG cable, and a Lenovo USB 3 to Ethernet adapter.

If I plug the Ethernet adapter into my phone (using the OTG cable of course) it loads the cdc_ether driver and sets up the interface eth0 (I ran `cat /proc/kmsg`).

However, when I do the same on my Nexus Player, it doesn't do either (however the kernel still picks up that I plugged it in).

I don't know a huge amount about Linux kernel development, but both seem to have cdc_ether.c in their kernel sources. Any ideas?